# Are finite-dimensional Banach spaces superreflexive?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm wondering if every finite-dimensional Banach space is superreflexive. I've tried it via the definition by I got stuck. Is there a property or a result that I may have in consideration? Or does this property not hold for every finite-dimensional Banach space?

Thank you for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Banach space is super-reflexive iff it is [uniformly convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space) for an equivalent norm (Theodore W. Palmer, *Banach Algebras and the General Theory of Star-algebras*, p.82-83). Since every Hilbert space is uniformly convex, every finite-dimensional Banach space is super-reflexive.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and your help!!

Answer (score 3):

A Banach space $X$ is [super-reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Super-reflexive_space) if every Banach space $Y$ finitely representable in $X$ is reflexive.  Now if $X$ is finite-dimensional and $Y$ is finitely representable in $X$, $Y$ must also be finite-dimensional with dimension at most the dimension of $X$, because every finite-dimensional subspace of $Y$ must be isomorphic to a subspace of $X$ and therefore has dimension at most that of $X$.  But every finite-dimensional Banach space is reflexive.  Therefore every finite-dimensional Banach space is super-reflexive.

Comment: Of course!! Thank you very much!